# To prove , if Aut$ (G)$ is trivial then $x^2=e , \forall x \in G$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

If for a group $G$ the only automorphism is the identity automorphism , then how do we prove that $x^2=e ,\forall x \in G $ ? I have only been able to prove that $G$ is abelian ; Please Help .

Comment: There is an even stronger conclusion: the group $G$ has order $1$ or $2$. Any abelian group satisfying $x^2 = e$ for all elements $x$ has a non-identity automorphism if the group contains more than two elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $G$ is abelian, $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism. By hypothesis it has to be equal to the identity, so $x^{-1} = x \implies x^2 = e$.

Answer (score 5):

If $G$ is abelian, consider the map $x \to x^{-1}$.